# Stop enabling Radiobutton after button click?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, radio-button

I have radio buttons in my project which should get disabled if one of the 2 options from a list of 4 attributes is selected. This is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpLType" runat="server" CssClass="drp">
 <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">Professional</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="1">Enterprise</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="2">Maintanence</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="3">Reporting</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I used javascript for this purpose:

```
function funMeapSupportValidate(val)
{
  switch(val)
    {
        case "0" :                             
            document.getElementById('<%=this.rdoMeapSupport.ClientID%>').disabled = false; 
            break;
        case "1" :
            document.getElementById('<%=this.rdoMeapSupport.ClientID%>').disabled = false; 
            break;                
        case  "2" :
            document.getElementById('<%=this.rdoMeapSupport.ClientID%>').check = false;   
            document.getElementById('<%=this.rdoMeapSupport.ClientID%>').disabled = true; 
            break;                
        case  "3" :
            document.getElementById('<%=this.rdoMeapSupport.ClientID%>').check = false;   
             document.getElementById('<%=this.rdoMeapSupport.ClientID%>').disabled = true; 
            break;                
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

At my backend code:

```
protected void drpLType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (drpLType.SelectedValue == "Professional")
    {
        rdoMeapSupport.Enabled = true;
    }

    if (drpLType.SelectedValue == "Enterprise")
    {
        rdoMeapSupport.SelectedValue = null;
        rdoMeapSupport.Enabled = true;
    }

    if ((drpLType.SelectedValue == "Maintanence") || (drpLType.SelectedValue == "Reporting"))
    {
        rdoMeapSupport.Enabled = false;
        rdoMeapSupport.ClearSelection();
    }

}
```

Now the problem is there are two buttons on my website. Whenever I click those buttons, the radio buttons get activated even when I have selected `Maintenance` or `Reporting` . How do I disable that?

On my page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Tab1.CssClass = "Clicked";
        MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;

        if (drpLType.SelectedValue == "Professional")
        {
            rdoMeapSupport.Enabled = true;
            rdoMeapSupport.SelectedValue = "Yes";
        }

        drpLType_SelectedIndexChanged();
    }

    drpLType.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:funMeapSupportValidate(this.value);");
}
```

Comment: Did it occur to you that on page postback the `drpLType_SelectedIndexChanged` event wont fire?

Comment: so should i call the function on my page load?

Comment: It doesn't appear that the event is hooked up in your asp.net code - are you setting it up in code-behind or did you just forget to hook it up?

Comment: i'm calling the js at my page load. but still nothing is happening.

Comment: are you using any ajax update panels? you are attaching onchange event on page load to dropdown, you should call function directly or call C# code that is in selectedindex change event again. Use jquery document.ready.

Comment: @rs i don't know ajax or jquery. :( can you help me out with the code?

Comment: Try using `AutoPostback = "true"` in the dropdownlist markup on aspx page. Also, you have not registered the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event. If you use `OnSelectedIndexChanged`, javascript functions are not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the error in the following manner.

```
protected void drpLType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (drpLType.SelectedValue == "1")
  {
   rdoMeapSupport.Enabled = true;
  }

  if (drpLType.SelectedValue == "2")
  {
   rdoMeapSupport.SelectedValue = null;
   rdoMeapSupport.Enabled = true;
  }

  if ((drpLType.SelectedValue == "3") || (drpLType.SelectedValue == "4"))
  {
   rdoMeapSupport.Enabled = false;
   rdoMeapSupport.ClearSelection();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I used this

```
<INPUT type="radio" name="myButton" value="theValue"
onclick="this.checked=false;
alert('Sorry, this option is not available!')">
```